# How to avoid footer overlapping image above it in a div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to avoid my footer overlapping an image placed at bottom right corner inside a div above the footer. I have applied z-index to the container having the bottom right image, but it is still being overlapped by the footer.

The CSS I am applying looks like this

```
.content_body
    {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background: #E6E6E0;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 800px;
     background-image: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/saturation.png) ;
    background-position: right bottom; 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     z-index: 1;
    }


       #footer
        {
       background: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/bg2.jpg) #E6E6E0;
       color: white;
    font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
     line-height: 1.5em;
     padding: 40px 50px 50px 50px;
     clear: both;
     border-top: solid #000033 5px;
     }

   .design_by
      {
     float:     right;
     font-size: 2.4em;
     font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;
     color:     white;
   }

   .copyright
  {
  float:     left;
   font-size: 2.4em;
  font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;
   color:     white;
       }


 <div class="content_body"> 
    hello
 </div>

 <div id="footer">
    <div class="copyright">
       <a href="#">mine.com</a> &copy copyright 2013 all rights reserved.
    </div>  

   <div class="design_by">  
       Design by <a href="http://types4u.org" target="http://types4u.org">types 4 u</a> 
   </div> 
   </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjXxk/4/) Example

Comment: I'm looking at http://fiddle.jshell.net/CjXxk/4/show/ 

Are you saying you want the picture of the man to be on top of the footer?

Answer (score 0):

Make that image in a separate div and give it absolute positioning within a relatively positioned parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/CjXxk/10/

The whitespace below the image is actually because there is a bar of whitespace in the image itself.

```
.saturation-image
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/saturation.png);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rethink the code that you are working with. Because you're setting the picture to be the background image of the content body, it will always be behind the footer because the footer position is fixed on top of the content body. You will have to put the image in a separate div.

I updated your fiddle to the code below. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/CjXxk/13/

```
 <div class="content_body"> 
     hello
</div>

<div class="picture">
    <img src="http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/saturation.png" />
</div>

<div id="footer">
     <div class="copyright">
         <a href="#">mine.com</a> &copy copyright 2013 all rights reserved.
     </div>  

     <div class="design_by">  
         Design by <a href="http://types4u.org" target="http://types4u.org">types 4 u</a> 
     </div> 
</div>
```

And then the CSS:

```
.picture {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

.content_body
    {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background: #E6E6E0;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 800px;
    }

#footer
    {
    background: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/bg2.jpg) #E6E6E0;
    color: white;
    font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 40px 50px 50px 50px;
    clear: both;
    border-top: solid #000033 5px;
    }

.design_by
    {
    float:     right;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;

    color:     white;
    }

.copyright
    {
    float:     left;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;
    color:     white;
    }
```